# Indexing Computed Column of 2 largest integers

Tags: sql-server, indexing, calculated-columns

According to Sql Server, Any computed column can be indexed only when it is deterministic. 
ie., *consider columns a,b, and c are of INT datatype and c = a+b*. Now column C can be indexed but **when column a or b holds the largest Integer value it will throw the Arithmetic Error, is there any solution ?

Thanks.

Comment: This looks like the type of question that could be answered by yourself with 5 minutes of effort.

Comment: Or, given that my comment is 2 minutes old, and I posted it before opening a query window and wrote my answer, maybe 5 minutes is a high estimate.

Comment: I tried and got this arithmetic overflow error. But interested to know about any solution. may be last line in the question is wrong.

Comment: What do you *want* in terms of a solution?

Answer (score 2):

```
create table TA (
    ID int not null primary key,
    a int not null,
    b int not null,
    c as a+b
)
go
create index IX_TA_c on TA (c)
go
insert into TA(ID,a,b) values (1,1,2147483647)
```

The insert gets:

```
Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.
The statement has been terminated.
```

If you want the calculation to always work, change the calculation so that at least one of the columns is forced to be a `bigint` (and so the maths and the resultant type of `c` are all `bigint` also):

```
    c as CAST(a as bigint)+b
```